# Where is my event log hidden?

Tags: c#, .net, logging, event-log

I'm writing to the event log with the following code:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var source = "TestSource";
    var logName = "TestLog";

    if (! EventLog.SourceExists(source))
    {
        EventLog.CreateEventSource(source, logName);
    }

    EventLog.WriteEntry(source, $"Testing.  Message @ {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

Where can I find it in the Event Log Viewer window?

[image: My empty event log]

Answer (score 0):

Refreshing the log **doesn't work**.  You have to **close the event viewer** and open it again, then... it's there.

[image]

*sigh*...